# transitivity of log dependencies

Tags: c, dependencies, shared-libraries

Context: a classic linux system (archlinux) with a gcc toolchain

My program (let's call it `P`) depends on a shared lib of mine (let's call it "foo" or `libfoo.so`)

`libfoo.so` got a public header `foo.h` and `P` includes it in one of its files.

`libfoo.so` depends on the `pthread` lib for several public functions (among other functions present in `foo.h`) but P does NOT use those functions.

The problem is, when I link P with libfoo.so, the libpthread is requested and I don't understand why and how to fix this.

Comment: Add `-pthread` to your GCC command line.

Comment: and I don't want to link against libpthread because P does not use any of the libpthread fonctionnalites :)

Comment: but P depends on libfoo, and libfoo depends on pthread, so P depends on pthread. you need the headers

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571300/incorporate-so-into-another-so-without-dependency. And as users of libfoo do not use pthread, removing dependency to pthread from foo.h is a good idea too.